# How to stretch a bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am porting a Java game to Android and the graphics in this game will not render correctly if the dimensions are not a square. Thus, the screen will not fit exactly onto my device. Is there anyway to stretch a bitmap, which contains the drawings, like an image? I know there is `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`, however this changes the pixel dimensions and thus the view will not render correctly. I want the dimensions to be the same, but the image should fill the whole screen. I can deal with distortions.

Comment: Have you tried this response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113368/4123144)

Comment: Set the image as **background**. It will be stretched.